How to calculate total ways for sequential card draws with specific constraints?
I am trying to calculate the total number of ways to draw cards sequentially from a standard deck of 52 cards under specific constraints. Here is the setup:
First Draw: Draw 4 cards such that at least 1 card has a value greater than 8 (values greater than 8 are 9, 10, J, Q, K, A).
Second Draw: Draw 4 more cards from the remaining 48 cards with no restrictions.
Third Draw: Draw 12 cards from the remaining 44 cards with no restrictions.
Fourth Draw: Draw another 12 cards from the remaining 32 cards with no restrictions.
Fifth Draw: Draw another 12 cards from the remaining 20 cards with no restrictions.
At the end, 8 cards will remain in the deck.
My Question:
How can I calculate the total number of ways to perform these sequential draws?
Specifically:
How do I ensure the constraint for the first draw (at least one card with a value greater than 8) is correctly accounted for?
How do I combine this constraint with the unrestricted draws that follow?
Any explanation or breakdown of the calculations would be greatly appreciated!

Are you at all concerned about the cards drawn in each draw apart from the first one, or the hand of cards you will hold with the constraints on the first draw ?

@trueblueanil No, the constraints apply to first draw only.

The only draw that has a restriction on it is the first draw. To calculate the number of ways to draw 4 cards such that at least 1 card has a value greater than 8, we can use complementary counting.
The total number of ways to draw 4 cards from a full deck is $\binom{52}{4}$. There are $32$ cards with value 8 or below, so the number of ways to draw 4 cards such that none of them have value greater than 8 is $\binom{32}{4}$. Hence, the total number of ways to draw 4 cards such that at least 1 card has a value greater than 8 is $\binom{52}{4}-\binom{32}{4}=234765$.
For the rest of the draws, since there are no restrictions, we can just directly apply the choose function. There are $\binom{48}{4}$ ways for the second draw, $\binom{44}{12}$ for the third, $\binom{32}{12}$ for the fourth, and $\binom{20}{12}$ for the fifth.

Do I need to multiply or add all in the end?

@HarnamSingh You multiply everything at the end to count the number of ways to perform each of the defined drawings.
